# My Javascript for loop stops after 1 iteration

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

Hi Guys i hope you can help me.

I have this code which loops through an array with different objects inside and it compares the content of one of the attributes with the content of a given array. Now it works fine, the only problem I have is that it stops after only 1 iteration (this happens with the first loop, not the second one).

Here's the code. I hope you guys can help me.

```
var checkIfChecked = function () {

for (var i=0; i < recepten.length; i++) {

    var kanIkHetMaken = true;

    var ditRecept = recepten[i];

    for (var i=0; i < ditRecept.nodigeIngredienten.length; i++) {

        var dezeIngredienten = ditRecept.nodigeIngredienten[i];

        var index = checked.indexOf(dezeIngredienten);

        console.log(index);

        if (index === -1) {

            kanIkHetMaken = false;
            return;

        }

    }

    if (kanIkHetMaken === true) {

    document.getElementById(ditRecept.id).style.display = "block";

    }

    console.log('1e recept gedaan');    

}};
```

Comment: Try to give different variable name in the second for loop.

Comment: You're using `i` for both loops.

Answer (score 1):

Change the variable for the inner loop to `j` and take a `break` instead of a `return`.

```
for (var j = 0; j < ditRecept.nodigeIngredienten.length; j++) { // change i to j
    var dezeIngredienten = ditRecept.nodigeIngredienten[j]; // use j
    var index = checked.indexOf(dezeIngredienten);
    console.log(index);
    if (index === -1) {
        kanIkHetMaken = false;
        break;  // exit the inner loop
    }
}
```

A little improvement with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
kanIkHetMaken = ditRecept.nodigeIngredienten.every(function (dezeIngredienten) {
    return ~checked.indexOf(dezeIngredienten);
});
```

Comment: Yes that did it! Thanks! Also I'm sorry if this was a stupid question, i'm still a student and learning javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable `i` in the both the loops. So when the inner loop gets over the outer loop checks the updated value of i for comparison.
Use different variable for inner loop like `j`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return;` with `continue;`.

`return` terminates the function.
`break` terminates the loop.
`continue` terminates that iteration and moves on to the next.

Comment: I deleted this answer for a second because I thought that maybe I had ignored your statement about it being the first loop, but I'm not certain that's the case. There's nothing else that will cause your loop to terminate early, so I'm thinking what you wanted was a `break`. It's difficult to tell because the code is written in a foreign language, haha.

Comment: Yeah i did what @FoPi said and I also replaced return with continue and now it works so thanks! And sorry haha I should have translated it first.